# How to "port" a current Win7 host into a VMWare image?

Tags: windows, linux, vmware

I'm planning on replacing my current host OS with a linux distro and then load the replaced OS as a virtual machine for apps that require Windows. Does anybody have a clue if something like this is possible and where to start ?

Comment: The term in vogue for this process is "p2v"'ing (physical to virtual).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VMware provides [vCenter Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) for free:

> Automate and simplify physical to virtual machine conversions as well as conversions between virtual machine formats with VMware vCenter Converter. Use the intuitive wizard-driven interface of VMware vCenter Converter to transform your physical machines to virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken VmWare Workstation has a built in feature to Virtualize a Physical Machine.